# C# Doughnut to datatable

Tags: c#, .net, charts

In my MySQL database I have a table with customers, two columns are named HoursUsed & HoursAvailable. With an SQL query I get the selected customer and fill it in a datatable.

Now I want to display in the dougnut chart the HoursUsed & HoursAvailable but it fills up the whole chart with 100% instead of 2 pieces.

How can I achieve this, First I created only one Series, then I tried to add another one but I get the same result.

I tried the following code:

```
chartHoursCustomer.DataSource = WorkData; //Datatable
        chartHoursCustomer.Series["HoursAvailable"].YValueMembers = "HoursAvailable";
        chartHoursCustomer.Series["HoursUsed "].XValueMembers = "HoursUsed ";
        chartHoursCustomer.DataBind();
```

Datatable: (Only 1 row because my SQL query is Select * FROM Customers WHERE ID = CustomerID)

```
HoursAvailable HoursUsed
50              44
```

Comment: Can you show the data for WorkData datatable you are retrieving?

Comment: Edited my post to display datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int ColumnCount = WorkData.Columns.Count;
string[] XPointMember = new string[ColumnCount];
int[] YPointMember = new int[ColumnCount];

for(int cnt = 0; cnt < ColumnCount; cnt++)
{
  // This is assuming that you actually retrieve one row.
  XPointMember[cnt] = WorkData.Rows[0][cnt].ToString();
  YPointMember[cnt] = Convert.ToInt32(WorkData.Rows[0][cnt]);  
}

Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(XPointMember, YPointMember);
```

Comment: but your data points are based on your columns. since you only have one row, you would actually should be seeing only one doughnut with no division. have you tried it already>?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were. That's why I asked him for the sample data to see what he wants to show in the chart.

Comment: What I do expect to see is 2 slices one showing the HoursAvailable and one slice show HoursUsed.